# Drag and drop rows in a table without swapping

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-template

I've been searching for a way to do this in Angular. All the examples I have found online show the same use case where you can drag a row to another row, then the target row gets swapped in the place of the initial row.
But that is not what I am looking for.

Let's say I have this table of 3 columns by 5 rows:

```
Slot1, Bananas, $1.00 
Slot2, <empty>,  
Slot3, <empty>,
Slot4, Oranges, $2.00
Slot5, <empty>,
```

I'd like to drag Bananas and its price to the Slot5, leaving Slot1 empty, like so:

```
Slot1, <empty>, 
Slot2, <empty>,  
Slot3, <empty>,
Slot4, Oranges, $2.00
Slot5, Bananas, $1.00
```

Another use case I am looking for: Drag a row onto an existing row, and instead of swapping the row, it bumps it down, like so:

```
Slot1, <empty>, 
Slot2, <empty>,  
Slot3, <empty>,
Slot4, Bananas, $1.00
Slot5, Oranges, $2.00
```

Any idea?

Comment: have you tried this lib? https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-drag-drop this is the one I use for most of my drap and drop lists/tables

Comment: Interesting. Although I am not seeing an example where you have empty row. Would than be possible?

Comment: I think it is (I haven't needed to do something like that). You may need to have a group of `<td>` inside a div and make that `<div droppable draggable >`. Not sure though, need to try.